# Intel-microcode not available on additional drivers

Tags: drivers, 18.04, intel, ubuntu-mate, microcode

When I used Ubuntu 16.04, intel-microcode was available in the additional drivers tab. But it's no longer showing up on Ubuntu MATE 18.04. I ran `apt-cache policy intel-microcode` and found that I don't have the it installed. Moreover, I get the following with a `dmesg` command:

```
sudo dmesg | grep --color -i "microcode"
[sudo] password for sakib: 
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x22 (or later)
[    0.803747] microcode: sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x19
[    0.803800] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

I'm a little worried because of the recent spectre-meltdown vulnerability. I googled a bit and researched here and there and it seems like this option has been deliberately removed, which I think makes my system vulnerable...

So, should I keep my system as it is or install intel-microcode manually?

Comment: Go ahead & install, can't hurt. It was removed from additional drivers because both the intel & amd microcode packages were supposed to be added as deps of the kernel. That idea was pulled for a time though seems to have recently happened somewhat. In 16.04 both packages are a dep of the latest linux-image-generic (4.4.0.125.131) & linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.13.0.42.61) & linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge (4.15.0.21.43). Why this isn't yet instituted in 18.04 yet no idea..

Comment: I've had a bug on this for some time https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1758689